# Creating a reusable component that has dynamic children

Tags: c#, wpf

I've been trying to search for a solution, but I don't quite know what to search for. I basically want to create a reusable component that has a top and bottom toolbar, like this:

```
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Start" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource ToolbarColor}">
        <!-- Top toolbar content-->
    </StackLayout>

    <!- ??? -->

    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="End" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource ToolbarColor}">
        <!-- Bottom toolbar content -->
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

I then want to be able to use it like so:

```
<ToolbarComponent>
    <!-- Contents -->
</ToolbarComponent>
```

What I don't know how to do, is the markup for the ToolbarComponent, what do I put where the ??? is, so that the page content I specify gets inserted in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing to do would be to create two separate UserControls for the toolbars.

Then use them like this.

```
<StackLayout>
    <controls:TopToolbar/>

    <!-- Contents -->

    <controls:BottomToolbar>
</StackLayout>
```